# Unable to store huge strings in-memory

Tags: python, regex, linux, python-2.7

I have data in the following form:

```
#@ De
A B C.
#@ dabc
xyz def ghi.
#@ <MyName_1>
Here is example.
#@ Df
A B C.
#@ <MyName_2>
De another one.
#@ <MyName_3>
Df next one.
#@ dabc1
xyz def ghi.
#@ <MyName_4>
dabc this one.
```

Convert it into the following form:

```
A B#1 C. //step 1 -- 1 assigned to the first occurrence of A B C.
xyz def#1 ghi. //1 assigned to first occurrence of xyz def ghi
Here is example
A B#2 C. //step 1 -- 2 assigned in increasing order
B#1 another one. //step 2
B#2 next one.
xyz def ghi.
def#1 this one.
```

// Here stand for comments and are not are part of the output.

The algorithm is the following.

1. If the second line following #@ gets repeated. Then, append to the
   middle word#number, where number is a numeric identifier and is
   assigned in increasing order of repetition of the second line.
2. Replace #@... with word#number where ever it occurs.
3. Remove all #@ where the second line is not getting repeated.

In order to achieve this I am storing all the triples and then finding their occurrences in order to assign numbers in increasing order. Is there some other way to achieve the same in python. Actually my file is 500GB and it is not possible to store all the triples in-memory in order to find their occurrences.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Ok. Can you please illustrate how to do the same using database...as I am novice at using databases in python

Comment: How does the second line get converted from `A B C.` to `A B#1 C.`? (I'm guessing the `//` comments are not part of the output?) I don' see any of the three rules that should make this happen.

Comment: @abamert Yes you are correct // are comments. I am using them in order to illustrate the point.

Comment: If all else fails, using a 64-bit version of Python should do the trick.

Comment: Meanwhile, the fact that your file is 500GB doesn't necessarily mean this would take too much memory; that depends on how many distinct triples you have. How many is that? Are you sure you're not wasting memory in some other way (e.g., by `readlines()`-ing the whole file into memory before processing, or by building a giant list instead of writing one line at a time, etc.)?

Comment: @abarnert I am afraid there are a lot of distinct triples in my file :(

Comment: @kindall: Wow, imagining the swap thrashing on a multi-TB dictionary, even on an SSD drive…

Answer (score 1):

If you need something that's like a dict, but too big to hold in memory, what you need is a key-value database.

The simplest way to do this is with a `dbm`-type library, which is a very simple key-value database with almost exactly the same interface as a `dict`, except that it only allows strings for keys and values, and has some extra methods to control persistence and caching and the like. Depending on your platform and how your Python 2.7 was built, you may have any of:

- [`dbm`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dbm.html)
- [`gdbm`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gdbm.html)
- [`dumbdbm`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dumbdbm.html)
- [`dbhash`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dbhash.html)
- [`bsddb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bsddb.html)
- [`bsddb185`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bsddb185)
- [`bsddb3`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bsddb3)
- [`PyBSDDB`](http://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb.htm)

The last three are all available on PyPI if your Python install doesn't include them, as long as you have the relevant version of libbsddb itself and don't have any problems with its license.

The problem is that, depending on your platform, the various underlying database libraries may not exist (although of course you can download the C library, install it, then build and install the Python wrapper), or may not support databases this big, or may do so but only in a horribly inefficient way (or, in a few cases, in a buggy way…).

Hopefully one of them will work for you, but the only way you'll really know is to test all of the ones you have.

Of course, if I understand properly, you're mapping strings to integers, not to strings. You could use the [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dbm.html) module, which wraps any `dbm`-like library to allow you to use string keys but anything picklable as values… but that's huge overkill (and may kill your performance) for a case like this; you just need to change code like this:

```
counts.setdefault(key, 0)
counts[key] += 1
```

… into this:

```
counts.setdefault(key, '0')
counts[key] = str(int(counts[key]) + 1)
```

And of course you can easily write a wrapper class that does this for you (maybe even one that supports the `Counter` interface instead of the `dict` interface).

---

If that doesn't work, you need a more powerful database.

Most builds of Python come with [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) in the stdlib, but using it will require learning a pretty low-level API, and learning SQL, which is a whole different language that's very unlike Python. (There are also a variety of different relational databases out there, but you shouldn't need any of them.)

There are also a variety of query expression libraries and even full object-relational mappers, like [`SQLAlchemy`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) (which can be used either way) that let you write your queries in a much more Pythonic way, but it's still not going to be as simple as using a `dict` or `dbm`. (That being said, it's not that hard to wrap a `dbm`-like interface around `SQLAlchemy`.)

There are also a wide variety of non-relational or semi-relational databases that are generally lumped under the term [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL), the simplest of which are basically `dbm` on steroids. Again, they'll usually require learning a pretty low-level API, and sometimes a query language as well—but some of them will have nice Python libraries that make them easier to use.

Comment: [You're going to need a bigger boat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gciFoEbOA8)